# submit button just refreshes php

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required/>
  <label class="form-label" for="form">Pass</label>
</div>
    <button type="Submit" value="send" class="btn transparent btn-block" style="color: white;">Submit</button>
  </form>

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $password=$_POST['password'];

      if ($password=='password') {
        header("location:ari.html");
        exit();
      }
      else
        echo "Incorrect.";
    }
```

I'm beginning php currently and I'm trying to use a login method, but whenever I press my submit button my code refreshes and doesn't move onto the next page I indicated. (location:ari.html)
If I could get help on what I did wrong that would be great thanks.

Comment: There are no form-element with the `name` `"submit"` in your form. Also, the `action` attribute is required in a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" >
    <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required/>
  <label class="form-label" for="form">Pass</label>
</div>
    <button type="Submit" name="submit" value="send" class="btn transparent btn-block" style="color: white;">Submit</button>
  </form>
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $password=$_POST['password']=='password'?header("location:ari.html"):"Incorrect.";
}
?>
```

**have updated this code and working fine for me...hope u got the answer**

Comment: hmm... I tried this, but the incorrect part doesn't work. It directs to action no matter what password it is.

Comment: i tried it just now it is working fine for me...remove the action from the form tag and try again

Comment: Ah, i tried it again and removed the action. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you should consider using action attribute in form tag and point into some POST url that retrieve your data
use action line this

```
<form method="POST" action="/ari.php">
```

submit button refresh the page without action attribute it just point to current URL if you dont fill it

Comment: It seems that OP wants to redirect to ari.php ONLY IF `$password=='password'`.

Comment: Yes! thank you for commenting, but it doesn't work with my login php code. $password=='password'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

`<form method="POST">`

What happening is that when you are submitting the form it is sending data to the same page.

In this line:

`if (isset($_POST['submit']))` 
I found no tag with name='submit' attribute. You should put this in your submit button.

If you want to send it to another page then use the action attribute in form tag and point your data to that page like `action=yourpage.php`

Comment: Gotcha, I included what you mentioned action + name="submit". This does work, but how could you make this so $password=='password' only?

Comment: or could i do var_dump($_POST); instead?

Comment: You can just use simple echo in this case.